# Creating a Load More filter using a TListView Search - Firemonkey Mobile Application

Tags: delphi, listview, firemonkey, searchbar

I managed to make a "Search" bar through a TEdit that seeks whatever i type from inside
a ListView that gets its information from a DataBase and goes through a filter and updates the ListView's items on the fly after a key is pressed.

Now i am trying to learn how to implement a way of limiting the results i get in my ListView temporarily until i press a Show More button or something like that in order to get some more relevant results.

Since the Database might return over 500 results by the time i press "A" and that would be harsh to a mobile phone's capabilities so i need that feature to make my Search button more efficient.

Could someone give me some pointers on what i can use in order to make something like that?

EDIT.

The current code i am using for searching in the ListView is this...

```
   procedure TContactsForm.Edit1ChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
var
   Lower: string;
   i: integer;
begin
   Lower:= LowerCase(Edit1.Text.Trim);
   if Lower= '' then
   begin
     if Filtered then
       begin
       ListView1.Items.Filter := nil;
       ListView1.ItemIndex := BindSourceDB1.ComponentIndex;
       end;
     end
     else
     begin
       ListView1.ItemIndex := -1;
       ListView1.Items.Filter :=
       function(X: string): Boolean
       begin
         Result:= (Lower = EmptyStr) or LowerCase(X).Contains(Lower);
       end;
    end;
   end;

 function TContactsForm.Filtered: Boolean;
 begin
   Result := Assigned(ListView1.Items.Filter);
 end;
```

Comment: My first recommendation is to use something like a grid instead of a list view. When you're rapidly updating the list as the user types, a list view can lag behind majorly with many results.

Comment: Thank you, i will keep this in mind but i was thinking about the ListView component because i thought its cells were more flexible from the aspect that they could contain more things.

Comment: Consider limiting the number of returned results. Google does 4.

Comment: Can i do that when the ListView is populated from a Dataset through a BindSourceDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to model your select statement so it only returns a limited about of rows (you can always remove the limitation upon user request).

For SQLite, MySQL and PostgreSQL you'd use a `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT acolumn FROM atable WHERE afield LIKE :param LIMIT 4;
```

In SQL Server you'd have to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT column, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) as row FROM atable 
) a WHERE a.row <= 4
```

This has the added benefit that less data is generated and transmitted by the database.

When doing the full search you simple omit the limit clause.

If you want to keep the results you already have and just add to extra results, use a
 `LIMIT 20 OFFSET 5` clause (without the offset keyword the operands are reversed `LIMIT 5,20`).
You always want to limit so as to make the experience snappy.
Every new page, you fetch the next x records.

You can even do this in real time, as the user is scrolling the list down.
Fetch new records as he nears the bottom of the list.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, i think your answer made things a lot more clear for me. I will try and implement your way with the LIMIT because that's EXACTLY what i wanted but wasn't aware of the SQL Command. I will inform you of the results

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2005 and i see that i have to use something like the second block of code you gave to me but... can i modify it to get the next x records too like you told me with the LIMIT,OFFSET sql version?

In order to do this since i am using SQL Server 2005 trying to create a filter with ranging and appending in the client dataset will be somehow easier.... working on it.

Comment: Sure, just modify the final `where` to look for a range.

Comment: I managed to make it with an SQL Query that's quite simple and modified how many Rows the client dataset will be fetching each time i press a button. The SQL code needs some more tampering in order to make it less tiring for the Server i think.. since i haven't yet implemented the technique you told me but i have another question now. Is there a way for me to check if the Client DataSet has more information to fetch so i can deactivate the 'Show More' button in case it has no more info to get or something like that?

Comment: Better ask that in a new question. There are several options for that.